# Include blank option on a condition in select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I have to display list of countries which can be rated. If a country has already been rated then users cannot "unrate" it

```
# countries index
= render @countries

# countries/_country
= form_for country do |f|
  =  f.select :rating,
    Rating.options,
    include_blank: "False if country is rated. True otherwise"
```

I tried to pass a proc to include_blank option but it didn't work

I can use helper to calculate options which looks like this:

```
def rating_options(country)
   if country.rating.present?
     Rating.options
   else
     [""] + Rating.options
   end
end
```

Is there a better way to include blank option in the select tag on a condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass to `include_blank` option any helper methods or conditions

```
= form_for country do |f|
  = f.select :rating,
    Rating.options,
    include_blank: f.object.rating.empty?
```

Comment: thank you, the solution is so simple - I can calculate include_blank inline! I can even use country local variable - `include_blank: country.rating.blank?` For some reason I thought that I need lambda or helper for it